# Can Luks Be Used To Encrypt an NTFS Partition in Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, windows, encryption, luks

(And then Boot into Full Windows With Luks Running Silently In the Background)
I have a client that is completely unable to use Linux, but I was thinking maybe there was a way to setup their computer to look like it just runs windows, but actually use LUKS in place of truecrypt in light of the recent developments with truecrypt re: truecrypt website.

Anyone have any ideas?  I know it won't be as fast as running a native windows FDE solution, but I think it would be more secure due to its uniqueness.

Comment: TrueCrypt 7.1 is safe and secure, provided you get it [from the right place](https://opencryptoaudit.org/).

Comment: @Whaaaaaat First of all don't you mean 7.1a? And I still have heard conflicting reports from those who compile it themselves and the hashes matching...

Answer (score 0):

Luks works at the block level so theoretically you can put any filesystems you want inside it including NTFS.

But you wouldn't be able to boot directly into Windows and access it, except I guess if Windows was running on a virtual machine inside your Linux installation.

While setting it up is outside the scope of this site, you could use Bitlocker.

Comment: I know...I'm trying to dream up a solution where luks runs seamlessly in the background and still boots the windows 7/8/10 loader from a uefi bios with gpt partitioning.  i.e.  The user is constantly running linux for the kernel but never knows it. I know it is completely possible, but I am unsure how to achieve it.  It would essentially be running a vm, as you said, but to the user (and due to complete pass-through, the end user would be completely unaware)  I think running Ubuntu in essentially console mode only would achieve this.  I know it would be a lot of work but also a perfect soln.