# Encrypt usb ntfs hard drive?

Tags: encryption, usb-drive, ntfs

Is it possible to fully encrypt an ntfs usb hard drive from Ubuntu 15.10 without erasing the data on it?
Will I have to have a decryption program installed if I want to run it from a windows machine?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/553924/can-luks-be-used-to-encrypt-an-ntfs-partition-in-ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encrypt external devices using a cross-platform solution?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18751/how-to-encrypt-external-devices-using-a-cross-platform-solution)

Comment: @psusi that question still does not tell me if I would have to backup my data.

Comment: *"fully encrypt... without erasing the data on it"*? No. To fully encrypt it you'll have to copy all the data to an encrypted form, and then even if you had the space to leave a "plain text" copy of the unencrypted data, why? It wouldn't be encrypted, so what's the point?

Comment: because I want to keep my data. I am not sure if I have the hard drive space to transfer it on another device while I am encrypting my hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

NTFS can only be properly handled by Windows. It would be best to use a Windows machine to encrypt it.

Comment: I don't have Windows on my machine.